# sharing on facebook sdk not found FacebookSDK is gone

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

well guys, I feel a bit stupid but i have spent HOURS trying to figure out how to, and I just can't :(

i have gone here (facebook devs site)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/getting-started-with-the-ios-sdk/#samples

and also here to download https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

the thing is that, in every single "tutorial", they say, install the FacebookSDK, y have downloaded the .zip like one million times, and, first, you don't install a zip, so it's not about literally "installing", anyhow, I went through the folders and files, and I found one of the files I need, FBConnect.bundle and FacebookSDKResources.bundle
BUT, there's no such a thing like FacebookSDK.framework, I'm sure i have downloaded the correct file and everything, so the only thing I could say, and I'm not sure, it is that the file is incomplete, I have tried to run the samples, and they don't run, they say they can't find FacebookSDK.framework

Please, don't give me link to "follow the instructions", I've followed all of them, I wouldn't be here if not, what I need to know is if I already have the FacebookSDK.framewok? even when I cant see it (spotlight says I don't) neither in the files of the last version of github, and if I already have it, how can I correctly add it to my project (remember I dont have any FacebookSDK.framework, so is not as easy as drag en drop or those kind of things)

thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Well, I solve it, it seems that the link of github that i posted is incomplete, and as I thought, there were something missing
after looking a bit more, a friend from college told me he had the missing file, and it seems that the file "FacebookSDK-3.0.pkg" was missing, so, he sent it to me and now it is working, yes, I wasn't crazy, it was just incomplete and it was imposible to follow FB instructions
thanks anyway

Comment: I'm having the same issue here. If you could post me a link to download the missing files I would be so thankful! It has taken me an hour to figure where the darn framework is.

Comment: there you go
https://developers.facebook.com/ios/downloads/

Answer (score 3):

In case anybody found this annoying problem again.

https://developers.facebook.com/ios/downloads/

Find it form google "FacebookSDK-3.0.pkg"  (why facebook make it complicate to download this?)